# Wrong python interpreter being used when debugging embedded target

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cmake, clion

I'm running CLion (2017.3 RC) with MinGW-w64 (5.0.3) and using gcc/g++ (7.2.0) + CMake (3.9.3) on Windows 10 x64 to compile a target that embeds python (3.6.3 64 bit). Everything works fine when run, however when I try to debug it and step through with CLion, I get

`File "C:\Python36\Lib/site.py", line 178
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I have my PYTHONPATH pointing towards a Python 3 installation. I do not have Python 2 installed on my system yet it seems like a Python 2 interpreter is trying to use the Python 3 Lib. After some digging I noticed that MinGW-w64 has Python 2 bundled with it but even if I delete the libs, include, and exe, I get the same error.

Comment: Have you verified the CLion python interpreter version? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html

Comment: Had no interpreter set, configured it to use my python3 installation. But no luck the same issue is persisting.

Comment: What is your CLion version?

Comment: 2017.3 RC.

I can't test it yet but I have a feeling it might be the prerequisite mentioned here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/python.html

Comment: Setting "run.processes.with.pty" in the registry to false did not fix the issue either. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I learned that python2 has been embedded in gdb from version 7.0+. Because of this, if you try to run MinGW64's gdb (like trying to debug from CLion) and you have PYTHONPATH pointing towards a python3 installation, you'll run into a syntax error. This happens because the embedded python2 is trying to use the python3 libs.

[image: gdb failing with PYTHONPATH pointing towards a python3 installation]

I am still unable to debug my C++ target that embeds python but that's a different issue...